# google sheets, Make letters separated by comma given number of following columns. Not using app script, just formulas please

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm using the query function in google sheets... I want to select columns F to AB.

I need a cell that has the output `F,G,H,I... ,AB` so I can put it in the `Select` statement.

This formula should have 2 inputs, the starting letter (`F` in this case) and number of following columns (`22` in this case)

No app script code please. I know someone can do it with just formulas in one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create the value of `F,G,H,I... ,AB` by giving the start column letter of "F" and the number of columns of `22`.

  - For example, when the start column letter of "F" and the number of columns of `22` are given, you want to retrieve the value of `F,G,H,I... ,AB` and you want to use this like `=QUERY(A1:AB,"SELECT F,G,H,I... ,AB")`.
- You want to achieve this using the built-in functions of Google Spreadsheet without the Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Sample formula 1:

In this sample formula, in order to create the value of `F,G,H,I... ,AB` by giving the start column letter of "F" and the number of columns of `22`, I would like to propose the following formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1:"&ADDRESS(1,B1+COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1")),4))),4),"\d+","")))
```

- When `A1` and `B1` have the values of `F` and `22`, respectively, the flow of this formula is as follows.

  1. Using `COLUMN`, retrieve the column numbers.
  2. Using `ADDRESS`, retrieve the column letters from the column numbers. At that time, the row number os removed using `REGEXREPLACE`.
  3. Above formulas are used with `ARRAYFORMULA`.
  4. Using `TEXTJOIN`, join the column letters with `,`.

Result:

[image]

#### Sample formula 2:

In this sample formula, `=QUERY(A1:AB,"SELECT F,G,H,I... ,AB")` is created using above sample formula 1.

```
=QUERY(A1:AB,"SELECT "&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1:"&ADDRESS(1, B1 + COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1")), 4))), 4),"\d+",""))))
```

Result:

In this sample result, the range of `A2:AB7` is used for `QUERY`. So please be careful this. When the cells "A1" and "B1" are changed, the result of this formula is also changed.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this case, when the start column and the number of columns are more than the existing maximum columns, an error occurs, please be careful this.

#### References:

- [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373)
- [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)

### Added:

When you want to create `Col6, Col7, Col8 ... Col28` by giving the start column letter of "F" and the number of columns of `22`, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
="Col"&TEXTJOIN(",Col",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1:"&ADDRESS(1,B1+COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&"1")),4)))))
```

- In this case, please put `F` and `22` to the cells "A1" and "B1", respectively.

Comment: awesome. that works. would it be too much trouble to ask for the answer in `Colx` format too? so the input would be the same, the output would be `Col6` starting with `F` then `Col6, Col7, Col8 ... Col28` in this case.

Comment: @jason Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional request, I added it to my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

if your range is `F:AB` then you can skip `select` parameter or use:

```
=QUERY(F1:AB; "select *"; 0)
```

if the range is larger put the range in curly brackets and try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A1:AB}; "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; "Col"&COLUMN(F:AB)); 0))
```